# How to navigate to first fragment without recreating the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

So example i have 3 fragment

- fragment A with 1 edittext, and 1 button
- fragment B with 1 textview, and 1 button
- framgnet C with 2 textview and 1 button

fragment A with edittext data example "this is test" -> fragment B -> fragment C -> fragment A again

how to prevent fragment A recreate again when from fragment C, so the edittext input in fragment A not empty.

here my nav graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/firstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.fjr.simplenavigation.FirstFragment"
        android:label="fragment_first"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.fjr.simplenavigation.SecondFragment"
        android:label="fragment_second"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_secondFragment_to_thirdFragment"
            app:destination="@id/thirdFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="data"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:name="com.fjr.simplenavigation.ThirdFragment"
        android:label="fragment_third"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_thirdFragment_to_firstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/firstFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/firstFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

if i replace the code for `action_thirdFragment_to_firstFragment` to like this

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
        android:name="com.fjr.simplenavigation.ThirdFragment"
        android:label="fragment_third"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_thirdFragment_to_firstFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/firstFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="false"/>
    </fragment>
```

it will solve the problem, fragment A will not recreated and the edittext still have the input like on the description, but is there any other way?

the second question is how to passing the data back to fragment A (but with edittext still have an input like on the description)?

Comment: Please see my answer about using a ViewModel. I wouldn't recommend keeping your data in Fragment because it will never survive a configuration change (i.e. You will lose your data when you change from Portrait -> Landscape mode). The system re-creates your Fragment from scratch when that happens. ViewModel is Google recommended way of persisting your data across configuration changes.

Comment: If you want `A` to stay, then `app:popUpToInclusive="true"` should be `false`

Answer (score 0):

You can use either an `Activity` scoped or `NavGraph` scoped `ViewModel`, and store your variable in there.

```
class FragmentA : Fragment {
   ...
   private val viewModel by activityViewModels<ViewModelA>()

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       ...
       myEditText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {
            viewModel.text = s.toString()
        }
    })
   }
}

class ViewModelA : ViewModel() {
    ...
    var text: String = ""
}
```

In the above example, your `ViewModel` would live as long as your `Activity` lives. If you'd like to modify your ViewModel, you would reach it the same way in any other `Fragment`, and get the same instance of the `ViewModelA`

```
class FragmentC : Fragment {
    ...
    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<ViewModelA>() <-- gives you the same instance of the ViewModel
}
```

Read more about "Sharing data between Fragments" here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: thank you, it solved the problem, but i got new problems, so in FragmentA, I declare arguments in the nav graph. so when from FragmentC -> FragmentA, it will become ` findNavController().navigate(FragmentCDirections.actionFragmentCToFragmentA("data from fragment c"))`. Then in fragmentA i can get the value with args. the problem is i want to show toast with the value of that arguments, and everytime i navifate FragmentA to FragmentB, then pressback, the args in FragmentA called the toast again. how to prevent that?